Remove moving text from a video Davinci Resolve
I am new to Davinci resolve and am following this video to remove text from my video:



I followed this cut to cut and at frame 429, I get a proper static image to which I apply paint clone and time track it. Then I create a planar transform and merge it to the output. The node graph looks like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/jtJH31sF.png
This approach is working fine. The issue is that the video is made of slides and each slide has a transition sliding in effect. When the frame which has the text slides, it is having a little glitch and showing the text for some time.
